# tomcat could not run ant reload command

Tags: apache, tomcat, ant, manager-app

when i enter command ant reload the server generate eception.
I write the ant reload script in my buil.xml file.
But server could not reload it.
Exeption is

```
BUILD FAILED
E:\Work\projects\schoolguide_0_2\build.xml:182: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:860)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:203)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.AbstractCatalinaTask.execute(AbstractCatalinaTask.java:146)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask.execute(ReloadTask.java:72)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 1 second
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share build.xml

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception, it looks like ant could not connect(Connection refused) to your tomcat server.

Double check that tomcat has the manager webapp running and that ant is connecting with all of the correct information.

Tomcat, by default, does not have any manager web-app users enabled. You'll need to uncomment a user and give them a manager role in the tomcat-users.xml, found in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf.

That user, along with their password is then used by ant to connect to it.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users> 
but have same problem

Comment: Have you confirmed the manager webapp is loading? 

Goto localhost:8080/manager/html/. 

If you are prompted by your browser to enter a user/pass, the webapp is working correctly. 

Also, what is the full ant task to reload?